# Hide Javascript Code to Older Browser

Tags: javascript, browser, obsolete

Well I think this is kinda dumb but, I wonder if there's any way to hide Javascript code from older browsers without affecting the code for modern browsers.

Yes I know there's the `<noscript></noscript>` tag to show a message for older browsers, but sometimes very old browsers for any reason show the JS code as text if is not recognized.

I hope you understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script>
<!--
    Your code here
//-->
</script>
```